# play video in openmax using c++

Tags: c++, c, openmax

can anybody tell me example of c code for openmax, to play an video file located in local drive.
you can find header files at the link given below-
http://www.khronos.org/registry/omxal/

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use the audio.s() method, then reverse the autpout to video linking